Why Are Reads in a Cache Hierarchy Larger than Misses of the Smaller Caches
I'm profiling cache misses for an ARM Big.Little system and I am surprised to see that the Reads of Level i+1 are larger than the read misses of Level i.
Consider the following perf output:



Event Name
Count




raw-l1d-cache-rd
117,693,796


raw-l1d-cache-lmiss-rd
14,462,334


raw-l2d-cache-rd
37,135,536


raw-l2d-cache-lmiss-rd
376,050


raw-l3d-cache-rd
8,846,223



For example, there are ~14M L1 Cache read misses, but ~37M level 2 reads. Moreover, there are much more l3 reads than l2 misses.
I would have expected that reads in the next hierarchy to be caused by misses in the smaller cache.

Does your CPU do hardware prefetch into L1d?  That avoids (some) demand misses in the level it prefetches into, and generates misses in outer levels of cache if they don't also have a prefetcher that's keeping ahead of those requests.  What microarchitecture?  You say big.LITTLE but haven't even said whether this is one of the big or little cores, let alone which microarchitecture either of them is.
